# How to update to 3.12 kernel on EC2?

Tags: kernel, amazon-ec2, aws

Updating kernels on EC2 seems a nightmare.

I'm on saucy, currently on kernel 3.11.0-14-generic according to `uname -a`. There's a fix in 3.12 that I need, how can I get it?

I tried the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade) to get the below in my system log, and I had to edit the grub default to fix it:

```
kernel  /boot/vmlinuz-3.12.0-031200-generic root=LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs ro console=hvc0 

initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.12.0-031200-generic

can only boot x86 64 kernels, not xen-3.0-x86_32p

Error 13: Invalid or unsupported executable format

Press any key to continue...
```

How can I upgrade to 3.12?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you built a 64-bit kernel instead of a xen one. You need to make sure that the following configurations are correct:

```
CONFIG_HYPERVISOR_GUEST=y (3.10+ only)
CONFIG_PARAVIRT=y
CONFIG_XEN=y
CONFIG_PARAVIRT_GUEST=y
CONFIG_PARAVIRT_SPINLOCKS=y
```

And Xen pv console device support (Device Drivers|Character devices)

```
CONFIG_HVC_DRIVER=y
CONFIG_HVC_XEN=y
```

And Xen disk and network support (Device Drivers|Block devices and Device Drivers|Network device support)

```
CONFIG_XEN_FBDEV_FRONTEND=y
CONFIG_XEN_BLKDEV_FRONTEND=y
CONFIG_XEN_NETDEV_FRONTEND=y
```

And the rest (Device Drivers|Xen driver support)

```
CONFIG_XEN_PCIDEV_FRONTEND=y
CONFIG_INPUT_XEN_KBDDEV_FRONTEND=y
CONFIG_XEN_FBDEV_FRONTEND=y
CONFIG_XEN_XENBUS_FRONTEND=y
CONFIG_XEN_SAVE_RESTORE=y
CONFIG_XEN_GRANT_DEV_ALLOC=m
```

Then you need to build the kernel with:

```
make all -j <2*number_of_cores>
```

To make a deb package, just use `make deb-pkg`.

Source:

- http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Mainline_Linux_Kernel_Configs